# PHP XML UTF-8 with special characters throws errors

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I am having some issues receiving UTF-8 XML files back from DHL API. As long as I don't send it's way any special characters like ś or ó, everything works just fine, but with these characters my app crashes when trying to load XML file received from DHL throwing me errors:

```
Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: 
Opening and ending tag mismatch: AddressLine line 43 and Consignee 
in Entity, line: 53 in D:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\catch2.php on line 29

Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: 
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Consignee line 40 and res:ShipmentValidateResponse 
in Entity, line: 97 in D:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\catch2.php on line 29

Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of 
data in tag ShipmentValidateResponse line 1 in Entity, line: 98
in D:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\catch2.php on line 29
```

This is a XML I send

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... 
<AddressLine>address</AddressLine> 
<AddressLine>asfśó</AddressLine> 
...
```

What I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
Lines 40 to 43:

<Consignee>
<CompanyName>Person</CompanyName>
<AddressLine>address</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>asf??ddressLine>
...
```

Here is what happens around line 29:

```
$responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
    die('<P>Error sending request');
$responseXml = utf8_decode($responseXml);
$responseDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);
```

E:
Removing utf8_decode doesn't help much. Just a new error:

```
Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: 
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xF3 0x3C 0x2F 0x41 in Entity, line: 43 in D:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\catch2.php on line 29
```

E2:
hex dump

```
0000-0010:  3c 3f 78 6d-6c 20 76 65-72 73 69 6f-6e 3d 22 31  <?xml.ve rsion="1
0000-0020:  2e 30 22 20-65 6e 63 6f-64 69 6e 67-3d 22 55 54  .0".enco ding="UT
0000-0030:  46 2d 38 22-3f 3e 3c 72-65 73 3a 53-68 69 70 6d  F-8"?><r es:Shipm
```

line 43:

```
0000-0960:  4c 69 6e 65-3e 0a 20 20-20 20 20 20-20 20 3c 41  Line>... ......<A
0000-0970:  64 64 72 65-73 73 4c 69-6e 65 3e 61-73 66 3f f3  ddressLi ne>asf?.
0000-0980:  3c 2f 41 64-64 72 65 73-73 4c 69 6e-65 3e 0a 20  </Addres sLine>..
```

Comment: Well, the encoding for these characters is indeed not UTF-8. Option 1: You're not sending UTF-8 to the server and the server is just returning the bytes as is, option 2: there's a bug in the API.

Comment: It's probably option1. But how do I send utf-8? Isn't first line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" enough? I can see that their API receives my request with it.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` just informs the recipient that it should expect the content of the file to be UTF-8 encoded. That doesn't do anything for the actual encoding of the file, *you* are still responsible for actually delivering UTF-8 encoded content. I'd recommend you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and then try to figure out which encoding your content is in.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got it working now. Used incov to encode my data to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use `utf8_decode`!**

That's what's screwing up your encoding.
`utf8_decode` converts UTF-8 encoded text to Latin1 encoded text. That's not what you want or need. Just parse the XML as is without encoding conversion.

Comment: Doesn't help much, still get an error:
Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xF3 0x3C 0x2F 0x41 in Entity, line: 43 in D:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\catch2.php on line 29

Comment: Then the document is possibly incorrect from the beginning? Can you post a hex dump of the first line and line 43 of the document?

Comment: @user Just a thought: Maybe the API is returning the same bytes you are sending it without actually en- or decoding them. In that case, you are possibly not sending UTF-8 to begin with. Are you by any chance `utf8_encoding` your values as well?

Comment: Nope, no utf8_encoding.
Added dump to first post, it looks like crap in here.